# Rebuilding the Sphinx index fails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, sphinx

We have a problem while rebuilding the Sphinx index for one of our MySQL databases. Rotating and rebuilding the index fails repeatedly, and the system continues to use the old index. The database size has doubled in the last months and it contains now tables with more than 10 million rows. During rebuilding of the Sphinx index with

```
indexer --config our_config.conf --rotate --all
```

(generated by the UltraSphinx plugin used here), we get the following error in the Sphinx daemon log file searchd.log

```
WARNING: rotating index 'main': preread failed: failed to open 
~/etc/sphinx//sphinx_index_main.new.spi: No such file or directory; 
using old index
WARNING: rotating index 'main': preread failure reported
```

The error messages occurred in increasing frequency as the database grew larger. Full indexing takes now about 1 1/2 hours, and the index files together are larger than one GB. We updated the Sphinx Version from 0.9.8.1 to 2.0.4 to solve this problem, but it still exists. The server has about 4 GB memory, and the configuration file begins with

```
indexer {
  mem_limit = 1024M
}

searchd {
  read_timeout = 5
  max_children = 300
  log = ~/etc/sphinx/log/searchd.log
  port = 3313
  max_matches = 100000
  query_log = ~/etc/sphinx/log/query.log
  seamless_rotate = 1
  pid_file = ~/etc/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
  address = 127.0.0.1
}
..
```

Has anyone an idea how the problem can be solved? I guess there seems to be some kind of index size limit which has to do with the 2 GB limit, wich is the maximal value for a signed 32 bit integer and maximal value for file sizes on certain file systems. The ext3 file system we use on our Ubuntu/Debian systems allows up to 16 GB for files, but certain libraries may limit the file size in practice to 2 GB (see [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=3013) and [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=4891)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of indexer itself - it shows its progress during indexing, and might give clue as to the issue.

Comment: Yes, checking logs and outputs is always recommendable. It says someting like "collected xxx docs, xxx MB", but quits with the error mentioned above (No such file or directory; using old index; rotating index 'x': preread failure reported).

Comment: Is there enough disk space to contain the temportally files. Typically need 1.3 times the size of the index.

Comment: df -h says about 9 GB is free. But it may have something to do with a size limit, see the text I added below the question. Maybe some kind of 2GB/int32 limit.

Comment: Ok, the problem only occurs if we use the rake task of the plugin (rake ultrasphinx:index), which generates the indexer command. If we execute the indexer command directly, then it works. Therefore it is probably the plugin which causes the error, although I do not know why.

Comment: Possibly the plugin is running the command as a different user? Maybe a user that doesnt have full permission to do stuff in the data directory?

Comment: Please tell us what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data location.
It looks like Sphinx want's to create a temp index file (that's what the indexer does) at `~/etc/sphinx//sphinx_index_main.new.spi`. 
I see two things here, one is the ~, not sure if this works.
The other thing is the double `/`.

IIRC this is in the index part of your Sphinx config file.

Comment: I used the ~ only as abbreviation, the real path begins with /home/username. I noticed the double /, too, but I guess it is not the root cause because it worked until the database grew large.